# Defining custom filters with log4cxx

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx

I know Log4cxx supports filtering logs according to their severity level (error, warning,etc.), but is there a way to set custom filters for loggers (in the form of functions to be called upon evaluating a logger, for example)? 
I know that Boost.Log has this capability (one can set custom filters using function objects) but was not able to find something similar in Log4cxx.

Thank,
Omer.